# JSON returned data formatting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using code below to get JSON data:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult getBranchViaJson()
    {
       Json(getBranchList(AppSession.BranchID.Value));
    }


    private object getBranchList(int n)
    {

        var mybranchList = from p in getBranchs(n)
                 select new { p.Code, p.Name };
        return mybranchList.ToArray();
    }
```

Client side retain value : 
`[{"Code":000,"Name":"Milan"},
  {"Code":001,"Name":"Istanbul"},
  {"Code":002,"Name":"Baku"},]`

But I want to get like this:

```
[{000:"Milan"},{001:"Istanbul"},{002:"Baku"}]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to papulate select list of jQeury DataTable in Editable mode

Comment: So what is the **specific** problem you ran into that forced you to post this question on SO?  Are you having trouble with arrays?  Is the json API confusing?  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

```
[{000:"Milan"},{001:"Istanbul"},{002:"Baku"}]
```

is invalid JSON. Properties must be quoted like so:

```
[{"000":"Milan"},{"001":"Istanbul"},{"002":"Baku"}]
```

In order to achieve this output you could use a `Dictionary<string, string>` that the `JavaScriptSerializer` will serialize to the desired output. So simply call the `ToDictionary` extension method on your model in order to convert it to a dictionary:

Like that:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult getBranchViaJson()
{
    var branches = 
        from p in getBranchs(AppSession.BranchID.Value)
        select new { p.Code, p.Name };
    var model = branches.ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.Name);
    return Json(new[] { model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or if you want to keep your private method which returns an object you could make it return a dictionary:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult getBranchViaJson()
{
    return Json(getBranchList(AppSession.BranchID.Value), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private object getBranchList(int n)
{
    var mybranchList = from p in getBranchs(n)
             select new { p.Code, p.Name };
    return new[] { mybranchList.ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.Name) };
}
```

Notice that I used `new[] { model }`. That's because otherwise the JavaScriptSerializer won't produce a javascript array as required but a simple javascript object.

Remark: notice that I have added `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` so that this controller action can be consumed with a GET request which is disabled by default for actions returning JSON responses.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: my output like : [{"000":"Milan","001":"Istanbul","002":"Baku"}] it's helpful for me. Thanks.